# Enable openGL drawing in Photoshop CS5 on MacBook Pro?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, opengl

I've read unchecking this makes PS work faster.  But I noticed on my new macbook pro it says the graphics is "Intel HD Graphics 3000 OpenGL Engine".  So my graphics card is designed for openGL?  meaning I should leave this option enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see Adobe's knowledge base for the how and why behind OpenGL in CS4/5. You should find the information you require [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/404/kb404898.html).